# Primefaces filedownload class implementation error

Tags: primefaces, download

When I Implement primefaces FileDownload Class which is in Primefaces UserGuide at this point my IDE showing set method return type to void or change to constructor.

> public  FileDownloadController()

```
public class FileBean {

private StreamedContent file;

public FileDownloadController() {
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("yourfile.pdf");
file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/pdf",
"downloaded_file.pdf");
}
public StreamedContent getFile() {
return this.file;
}
}
```

what is the exact problem.

Comment: change `public FileDownloadController() {` into `public void FileDownloadController() {`

Comment: If change like you suggested IDE showing a warning "Change to Constructor"

Comment: Please select an answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code to like this..

package org.primefaces.examples.view;

```
 public class FileDownloadController {

private StreamedContent file;

public FileDownloadController() {        
    InputStream stream = ((ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getResourceAsStream("/images/optimusprime.jpg");
    file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "image/jpg", "downloaded_optimus.jpg");
}

public StreamedContent getFile() {
    return file;
}  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

that is because your class has a different name, to solve this change

```
    public FileDownloadController() to public FileBean()
```